# Unicorn & nginx error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn, vagrant

```
vagrant@lucid32:/vagrant$ bundle exec unicorn_rails -c config/unicorn.rb -D -d
{:unicorn_options=>{:listeners=>[], :config_file=>"config/unicorn.rb"},
 :app=>
  #<Proc:0xa1a6ef4@/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/bin/unicorn_rails:135 (lambda)>,
 :daemonize=>true}
Exception `Errno::EEXIST' at /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247 - File exists - tmp/cache
Exception `Errno::EEXIST' at /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247 - File exists - tmp/pids
Exception `Errno::EEXIST' at /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247 - File exists - tmp/sessions
Exception `Errno::EEXIST' at /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247 - File exists - tmp/sockets
Exception `EOFError' at /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/launcher.rb:46 - end of file reached
master failed to start, check stderr log for details
```

Unfortunately I have no idea how to check the stderr log and culd not find any relevant information.

Here's the config file:

```
working_directory "/vagrant"
pid "/vagrant/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"
stderr_path "/vagrant/log/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "/vagrant/log/unicorn.log"

listen "/tmp/unicorn.todo.sock"
worker_processes 2
timeout 30
```

And here is the nginx.conf file

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.todo.sock fail_timeout=0;
}


server {
  listen 80 default;
  # server_name example.com;
  root /vagrant/public;
  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
  location @unicorn {
      proxy_pass  http://unicorn;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
}
```

Now the thing is that the /tmp directory is not being created. So i created it and i get the same error, then i deleted it and i get the same error. and now i am stuck in an infinite loop.

I would appreciate any help about ho to make this work or at least how to read the error log.

EDIT: i was able to find the stderr file:

```
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:207:in `rename': Text file busy - (/vagrant/tmp/pids/0.2278780536507904.2128, /vagrant/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid) (Errno::ETXTBSY)
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:207:in `pid='
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:137:in `start'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:207:in `rename': Text file busy - (/vagrant/tmp/pids/0.8313958669768073.2187, /vagrant/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid) (Errno::ETXTBSY)
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:207:in `pid='
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:137:in `start'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:207:in `rename': Text file busy - (/vagrant/tmp/pids/0.9130633695817217.2190, /vagrant/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid) (Errno::ETXTBSY)
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:207:in `pid='
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:137:in `start'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:683 - No such file or directory - /vagrant/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid
Exception `Errno::ETXTBSY' at /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:207 - Text file busy - (/vagrant/tmp/pids/0.59100125503182.2237, /vagrant/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid)
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:207:in `rename': Text file busy - (/vagrant/tmp/pids/0.59100125503182.2237, /vagrant/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid) (Errno::ETXTBSY)
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:207:in `pid='
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:137:in `start'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:207:in `rename': Text file busy - (/vagrant/tmp/pids/0.4331021743697998.2271, /vagrant/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid) (Errno::ETXTBSY)
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:207:in `pid='
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:137:in `start'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:683 - No such file or directory - /vagrant/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid
```

Comment: Is there any additional configuration for your unicorn config file?

Comment: i've thrown in the towel, way too much frustration for something without immediate value. I've configured nginx to run with webrick and i'm happy with that

Comment: Robin, if you were running this on VirtualBox VM from inside a shared folder, this might be the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Unicorn process is running in background(-d),
type below command on teminal

```
ps aux | grep unicorn
```

and kill running unicorn process then start unicorn again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem (the `Text file busy` error), also running from a Vagrant VM. @destiel's comment helped me solve the problem: Apparently this is caused by running `rails` and `unicorn` from the Vagrant shared folder. After copying to the virtual drive, it worked fine. I'm running on a Windows 8 host, in case that matters.